# Identify this UK flower that looks like a snowdrop

Tags: identification

Spotted these in a garden in the UK in the middle of August. Thought they were snowdrops but it's the wrong time of year. Any ideas?

[image: Please identify this flower]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are Cyclamen - without being able to see the leaves and the height of the plants, I can't tell whether these are shop bought temporary visitors for autumn, or a naturalized hardy type. They might be Cyclamen hederifolium 'Alba' if naturalized https://www.jparkers.co.uk/3-cyclamen-hederifolium-alba-1000470c

Cyclamen bedding plants are available in the UK during September, intended for use in pots and tubs (or the ground) and will remain in flower till it gets very cold.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that looks right to me. More specifically, we saw these on the grounds of Grimsthorpe Castle, and they appeared to be growing wild.

Comment: Added link so you can see the hardy ones... the flowers are similar on all varieties

Comment: No worries - I'm just wondering who voted my answer down though (not you I imagine)... and why they did so.